# Kivy: How to get class Variables in Popup

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

procedure: First you have to add a Name and than the Programm will set a Beginner (function "umdie()") after that the Screen "Wurfelbeginn" will Show you the names of the Players and the number which they had  thorwn. 
After that you click on the Button "Wer beginnt?" to see who begins.

And now my problem: 
i want to Showthe variable "Beginner" from the class Variablen  in the popup, but if i call the variable nothing happens, but the console Shows the right names.

What i am doing wrong?

my main.py Code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, SlideTransition
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, ListProperty, StringProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.core.window import Window
from random import *


class Boxlayout(BoxLayout):
    pass


class Textinput(TextInput):
    pass


class Variablen():
    Spielernamen = []
    Beginner = 0
    Zweiter = 0

    def get_names(self, Namensabfrage):
        Name1 = Namensabfrage.name_1.text
        Name2 = Namensabfrage.name_2.text
        self.Spielernamen.append(Name1)
        self.Spielernamen.append(Name2)
        print(Variablen.Spielernamen)

    def umdie(self, Wurfelbeginn):
        if Wurfelbeginn.Würfel1 > Wurfelbeginn.Würfel2:
          self.Beginner = self.Spielernamen[0]
          self.Zweiter = self.Spielernamen[1]

        elif Wurfelbeginn.Würfel1 == Wurfelbeginn.Würfel2:
          self.Beginner = self.Spielernamen[0]
          self.Zweiter = Variablen.Spielernamen[1]
        else: 
          self.Beginner = self.Spielernamen[1]
          self.Zweiter = self.Spielernamen[0]

        print(self.Beginner)
        print(self.Zweiter)


class Namensabfrage(Screen):
    name_1 = ObjectProperty()
    name_2 = ObjectProperty()

    def save_names(self):
        vars = Variablen()
        vars.get_names(self)


class Wurfelbeginn(Screen, Variablen):
    Spieler1 = StringProperty("")
    Spieler2 = StringProperty("")
    Würfel1 = randint(1,6)
    Würfel2 = randint(1,6)
    WürfSp1 = str(Würfel1)
    WürfSp2 = str(Würfel2)

    def on_pre_enter(self):
        self.Spieler1 = str(Variablen.Spielernamen[0] + " würfelt: ")
        self.Spieler2 = str(Variablen.Spielernamen[1] + " würfelt: ")
        Variablen.umdie(self, Wurfelbeginn)


    def open_popup(self):
        the_popup = CustomPopup()
        the_popup.open()



class CustomPopup(Popup,Variablen):
    Beginnertext = StringProperty("")
    def on_pre_enter(self):
        self.Beginnertext = str(Variablen.Beginner +  "fängt an")
        print("Hallo")




class Manager(ScreenManager):
    namensabfrage = ObjectProperty(None)
    wurfelbeginn = ObjectProperty(None)


class ScreensApp(App):

    def build(self):
        m = Manager(transition=SlideTransition())
        return m


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ScreensApp().run()
```

and here screes.kv:

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<Namensabfrage>:

    name_1: name1
    name_2: name2

    Boxlayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        padding: 50
        spacing: 50
        Label:
            text: "gebt hier eure Namen ein"

        Textinput:
            id: name1
            size_hint: (1, .3)
            text: ""
            multiline: False

        Textinput:
            id: name2
            size_hint: (1, .3)
            text: ""
            multiline: False

        Button:
            text: "Bestätigen"
            size_hint:(1,.4)
            on_press: root.save_names()

        Button:
            size_hint: (1, .5)
            text: "Start"
            on_press: root.manager.current = "Screen2"



<Wurfelbeginn>:

    Boxlayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        spacing: 20

        Button:
            text: "Wer beginnt?"
            size_hint:(1,.4)    
            font_size: 20
            on_press: root.open_popup() 

        Label:
            text: root.Spieler1

        Label: 
            text: root.WürfSp1
            font_size: 30

        Label:
            text: root.Spieler2

        Label: 
            text: root.WürfSp2
            font_size: 30


<CustomPopup>:
    size_hint: .5, .5
    auto_dismiss: False
    title: "Beginner"
    BoxLayout: 
        Label: 
            text: root.Beginnertext
        Button: 
            text: "schließen"
            on_press: root.dismiss()


<Manager>:
    id: screen_manager

    namensabfrage: Namensabfrage
    wurfelbeginn: Wurfelbeginn


    Namensabfrage:

        id: Namensabfrage
        name: "Screen1"
        manager: screen_manager

    Wurfelbeginn:

        id: Wurfelbeginn
        name: "Screen2"
        manager: screen_manager
```

Answer (score 1):

## Display Who Starts in Popup Window

Please refer to the following explanations, example, and output for details.

## Explanations

### screens.kv

#### class <Namensabfrage>

Replace *root.save_names()* with *app.root.variablen.get_names(root)*, and pass *root* so that the newly created object, *Variablen* is accessible by the other classes.

#### Snippets

```
<Namensabfrage>:
    ...
        Button:
            text: "Bestätigen"
            size_hint:(1,.4)
            on_press: app.root.variablen.get_names(root)
```

#### class <Manager>

Add a call to customized method, *on_pre_enter_callback* and pass the newly created object, *app.root.variablen* so that it is accessible by the other classes.

#### Snippets

```
<Manager>:
    transition: SlideTransition()
    ...
    Wurfelbeginn:

        id: Wurfelbeginn
        name: "Screen2"
        manager: screen_manager
        on_pre_enter: self.on_pre_enter_callback(app.root.variablen)
```

### main.py

#### Mulitple Inheritance

There is no need for multiple inheritance. Removed "Variablen" from classes.

```
class Wurfelbeginn(Screen):
...
class CustomPopup(Popup):
```

#### class Variablen

1. Since string will be assigned to the attribute/variable *Beginner* and *Zweiter*, define them as string.
2. Fix a typo error in method *umdie*. Replace *self.Zweiter = Variablen.Spielernamen[1]* with *self.Zweiter = self.Spielernamen[1]*
3. Add a method __init__

#### Snippets

```
class Variablen():
    def __init__(self):
        self.Spielernamen = []
        self.Beginner = ''
        self.Zweiter = ''
...
    def umdie(self, Wurfelbeginn):
        ...
        elif Wurfelbeginn.Würfel1 == Wurfelbeginn.Würfel2:
          ...
          self.Zweiter = self.Spielernamen[1]
        else:
          ...
```

#### class Namensabfrage

1. Removed method *save_names*.
2. Initialized ObjectProperties (name_1, name_2) to *None*.

#### Snippets

```
class Namensabfrage(Screen):
    name_1 = ObjectProperty(None)
    name_2 = ObjectProperty(None)
```

#### class Wurfelbeginn

1. Add an *ObjectProperty* for new class attribute, *variablen*
2. Rename method *on_pre_enter* to a customized method, *on_pre_enter_callback*
3. Hook up the new *ObjectProperty* to the argument, *variablen*
4. Renamed *Variablen* to *variablen*
5. Pass *self* to method *umdie*
6. Pass object, *self.variablen* to class *CustomPopup*

#### Snippets

```
class Wurfelbeginn(Screen):
    variablen = ObjectProperty(None)
    ...

    def on_pre_enter_callback(self, variablen):
        self.variablen = variablen
        self.Spieler1 = str(variablen.Spielernamen[0] + " würfelt: ")
        self.Spieler2 = str(variablen.Spielernamen[1] + " würfelt: ")
        variablen.umdie(self)

    def open_popup(self):
        the_popup = CustomPopup(self.variablen)
```

#### class CustomPopup

In order to display who is the beginner, add a method *__init__* to populate the class attribute, *Beginnertext*.

#### Snippets

```
class CustomPopup(Popup):
    Beginnertext = StringProperty('')

    def __init__(self, variablen, **kwargs):
        super(CustomPopup, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.Beginnertext = str(variablen.Beginner + " fängt an")
        print(self.Beginnertext)
        print("Hallo")
```

#### class Manager

1. Add an *ObjectProperty*, *variablen*
2. Add a method __init__
3. Hook up the ObjectProperty (*variablen*) to instantiated object, *Variablen* (class Variablen).

#### Snippets

```
class Manager(ScreenManager):
    variablen = ObjectProperty(None)
    ...

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Manager, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.variablen = Variablen()     # Instantiate object Variablen
```

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from random import *


class Boxlayout(BoxLayout):
    pass


class Textinput(TextInput):
    pass


class Variablen():
    def __init__(self):
        self.Spielernamen = []
        self.Beginner = ''
        self.Zweiter = ''

    def get_names(self, Namensabfrage):
        Name1 = Namensabfrage.name_1.text
        Name2 = Namensabfrage.name_2.text
        self.Spielernamen.append(Name1)
        self.Spielernamen.append(Name2)
        print(self.Spielernamen)

    def umdie(self, Wurfelbeginn):
        if Wurfelbeginn.Würfel1 > Wurfelbeginn.Würfel2:
          self.Beginner = self.Spielernamen[0]
          self.Zweiter = self.Spielernamen[1]

        elif Wurfelbeginn.Würfel1 == Wurfelbeginn.Würfel2:
          self.Beginner = self.Spielernamen[0]
          self.Zweiter = self.Spielernamen[1]
        else:
          self.Beginner = self.Spielernamen[1]
          self.Zweiter = self.Spielernamen[0]

        print(self.Beginner)
        print(self.Zweiter)


class Namensabfrage(Screen):
    name_1 = ObjectProperty(None)
    name_2 = ObjectProperty(None)


class Wurfelbeginn(Screen):
    variablen = ObjectProperty(None)
    Spieler1 = StringProperty('')
    Spieler2 = StringProperty('')
    Würfel1 = randint(1, 6)
    Würfel2 = randint(1, 6)
    WürfSp1 = str(Würfel1)
    WürfSp2 = str(Würfel2)

    def on_pre_enter_callback(self, variablen):
        self.variablen = variablen
        self.Spieler1 = str(variablen.Spielernamen[0] + " würfelt: ")
        self.Spieler2 = str(variablen.Spielernamen[1] + " würfelt: ")
        variablen.umdie(self)

    def open_popup(self):
        the_popup = CustomPopup(self.variablen)
        the_popup.open()


class CustomPopup(Popup):
    Beginnertext = StringProperty('')

    def __init__(self, variablen, **kwargs):
        super(CustomPopup, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.Beginnertext = str(variablen.Beginner + " fängt an")
        print(self.Beginnertext)
        print("Hallo")


class Manager(ScreenManager):
    variablen = ObjectProperty(None)
    namensabfrage = ObjectProperty(None)
    wurfelbeginn = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Manager, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.variablen = Variablen()     # Instantiate object Variablen


class ScreensApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Manager()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ScreensApp().run()
```

### screens.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0
#:import SlideTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.SlideTransition

<Namensabfrage>:

    name_1: name1
    name_2: name2

    Boxlayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        padding: 50
        spacing: 50
        Label:
            text: "gebt hier eure Namen ein"

        Textinput:
            id: name1
            size_hint: (1, .3)
            text: ""
            multiline: False

        Textinput:
            id: name2
            size_hint: (1, .3)
            text: ""
            multiline: False

        Button:
            text: "Bestätigen"
            size_hint:(1,.4)
            on_press: app.root.variablen.get_names(root)

        Button:
            size_hint: (1, .5)
            text: "Start"
            on_press: root.manager.current = "Screen2"



<Wurfelbeginn>:

    Boxlayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        spacing: 20

        Button:
            text: "Wer beginnt?"
            size_hint:(1,.4)
            font_size: 20
            on_press: root.open_popup()

        Label:
            text: root.Spieler1

        Label:
            text: root.WürfSp1
            font_size: 30

        Label:
            text: root.Spieler2

        Label:
            text: root.WürfSp2
            font_size: 30


<CustomPopup>:
    size_hint: .5, .5
    auto_dismiss: False
    title: "Beginner"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: root.Beginnertext
        Button:
            text: "schließen"
            on_press: root.dismiss()


<Manager>:
    id: screen_manager
    transition: SlideTransition()

    namensabfrage: Namensabfrage
    wurfelbeginn: Wurfelbeginn


    Namensabfrage:

        id: Namensabfrage
        name: "Screen1"
        manager: screen_manager

    Wurfelbeginn:

        id: Wurfelbeginn
        name: "Screen2"
        manager: screen_manager
        on_pre_enter: self.on_pre_enter_callback(app.root.variablen)
```

## Output

Comment: It doesen't work.... and in your example Adam is the Beginner so his Name  must be as a text in the Textinput. You manually wrote the Name "Eve" in the Textinput. That is not the sence. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Does anyone else have a solution?

Comment: I have updated my post. Now it is displaying who starts (Beginnertext) in the Popup window correctly.